# Firestore won't write documents if placed at bottom while returning multiple promises

Tags: node.js, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Firestore won't create documents if placed the return statement like this:

```
return Promise.all([
  res.status(200).send({
    method: 'sendMessage',
    chat_id, 
    text: `${field1Val}`, 
    parse_mode: 'HTML'
  }),
  admin.firestore().collection('colName').doc(`docName`).set({ "field1": field1Val }, { merge: true })
])
```

Though the below code will create the Doc:

```
return Promise.all([
  admin.firestore().collection('colName').doc(`docName`).set({ "field1": field1Val }, { merge: true }),
  res.status(200).send({
    method: 'sendMessage',
    chat_id, 
    text: `${field1Val}`, 
    parse_mode: 'HTML'
  })
])
```

I use the first format with realtime database and it works perfectly. 
I don't know why Firestore wants the privilege of being at top.

I have waited for 15+ mins and refreshed the page still no sign of the document.

PS: I had re-initialized the project and installed new npm modules too. Didn't help XD

The complete code which I don't think is a problem cause the doc is created if I placed that command at top.

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import * as express from 'express'
import * as cors from 'cors'
import admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

const bot = express()

bot.use(cors({ origin: true }))

bot.post('/', async (req, res) => {

const commandSliced: string = JSON.stringify(req.body.message.text)

  let userMsg: string = ''

  if (commandSliced.startsWith(`!text`)) { 
    userMsg = userCommandSliced.replace('!text', '')
    let exclmCmd_array: string[];
    msg_array = userEMsg.split(/\b\s+/, 2)

    const field1val= userMsg.replace(msg_array[0], '')

  return Promise.all([                
    res.status(200).send({
      method: 'sendMessage',
      chat_id, 
      text: `${field1val}`, 
      parse_mode: 'HTML'
    }), 
    admin.firestore().collection('colName').doc(`docName`).set({ "field1": field1Val }, { merge: true })                
  ]) 

})
```

**EDIT:** This worked as suggested by Doug.

```
return admin.firestore().collection('colName').doc(`docName`).set({ "field1": field1Val }, { merge: true }).then(() => {
  return res.status(200).send({
    method: 'sendMessage',
    chat_id,
    text: `${field1Val}`,
    parse_mode: 'HTML'
   })
 })
```

Comment: Could you say some more about this code?  Are you running in Cloud Functions?  Maybe you could edit the question to give the complete, minimal code that reproduces the issue?  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @DougStevenson I have updated my code :D It is a telegram and if message starts with `!text` it will do the job else just a log statement which I haven't added above :')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issues are that:

1. `res.status(200).send()` doesn't return a promise, so it doesn't make sense to pass its value to Promise.all().
2. `res.status(200).send()` also [terminates the function immediately](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions), which means that after it executes, you shouldn't expect other asynchronous code (like your Firestore update) to work at all.

What you should do instead is wait until the Firestore update completes (by using the promise it returns), then send the response as the very last thing in the function.

Comment: But if I use realtime database it works perfectly. But I will love to try this. So I have to  add the `res.status(200).send()` inside of `admin.firestore().collection().doc().set({. . .}).then(() => { ... })` this way ?

Comment: If anything else worked, it depends on a race condition, which is not a good idea.

Comment: I have updated my question with with some modified code as you suggested. Can you say if that could be the correct way? That works nicely though :D

Comment: Since send() doesn't return a promise there is no point in returning the vaue.  It just terminates the function.

Comment: It should work fine then. Though I'm still wondering why my old code works if I use Realtime Database instead of firestore.

Comment: Because you were depending on a race condition.  Promises should be dealt with correctly without depending on timing issues.